# How do you Visualize a Huge Integer in Python?

Tags: python, string, int, largenumber

So, just for fun, I wanted to see the largest prime we have discovered yet with my own eyes (2^277,232,917 − 1 according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number)) which is a 23,249,425 digit number. Oh boy. So I started off with manually calculating the number in Python: `2**277232917-1` which would give me an answer...eventually...some day. After waiting a half an hour while one of my cores was throttled for the entire time, I started to look for a faster solution to solve exponents. I found [this gem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) on Wikipedia known as

> Exponentiation by Squaring

```
def exp_by_squaring(x, n):
    if n<0:
        return exp_by_squaring(1 / x, -n)
    elif x==0:
        return 1
    elif x==1:
        return x
    elif n%2==0:
        return exp_by_squaring(x * x,  n / 2)
    elif not n%2==0:
        return x * exp_by_squaring(x * x, (n - 1) / 2)
```

After plugging this into a python3 console and inputting `t=exp_by_squaring(2, 277232917)-1` and waiting for an..oh wait it's done! I love this concept. Now with this number I can `print(str(t))` and it's frozen again. Suppose I can let it write to a file over night `f=open("LargestPrime", "w") f.write(str(t)) f.close()`. Next morning with a single **23.2 MB** text file, trying to open it up it just freezes and throttles a core again. I guess it's too much to even display.

How would you accomplish this? Could you split the `int` into separate portions and then convert them to strings to write them to separate files? Would I save it in a different format? How could I shorten the time it takes to convert this 23M+ digit int to a string? How could I practically display such a large number? Am I completely missing something here?

Comment: Incidentally, `math.log(2**277232917-1,10)` is ~83,455,424, so the number in question has that many decimal digits. Calculating the number takes no time as such; it's the conversion to a string that takes forever. So, the main question is: why do you want a string representation of this number at all?

Comment: @DYZ *So, just for fun, I wanted to **see** the largest prime we have discovered yet*

Comment: @DYZ because I think it would be amazing to see the largest known prime number known so far in all it's impractical but impressive glory. Also, there's apparently a contest to find a prime number over 100M digits long with a $150,000 reward. Don't think I could do that any time soon but found so many cool things such as that Exponentiation by Squaring concept and Modular Exponentiation and  the Lucas–Lehmer primality test and what Mersenne Primes are. Don't think I'll be really diving into what these really are yet being in MAT 154 but can't hurt to get my feet a little wet in a future pond.

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number, the current record holder has been made this month and they show the first and last digits of the number, here is a snippet from Wikipedia:

```
Current record
The record is currently held by 2^82,589,933 − 1 with 24,862,048 digits, found by GIMPS in December 2018.[1] Its value is:

148894445742041325547806458472397916603026273992795324185271289425213239361064475310309971132180337174752834401423587560 ...

(24,861,808 digits omitted)

... 062107557947958297531595208807192693676521782184472526640076912114355308311969487633766457823695074037951210325217902591[6]

The first and last 120 digits are shown above.
```

You can see the digits yourself in python like this:

```
In [304]: t = pow(2,82589933)-1                                                                                                                                 

In [305]: n = 24862048-1000                                                                                                                                     

In [306]: a = pow(10,n)                                                                                                                                         

In [310]: f = t // a                                                                                                                                            

In [311]: len(str(f))                                                                                                                                           
Out[311]: 1000

In [312]: f                                                                                                                                                     
Out[312]: 1488944457420413255478064584723979166030262739927953241852712894252132393610644753103099711321803371747528344014235875600519775183265856491842931959708229506343343451097313699205342310641140595264767876746819332211781849375477107986211226534792788629942124472358169794644246737226991115661546889834987857788089927363336356512975433528625745217905541113567854803029538259231829040461918808066672007922224457105930988153887394047699962279207194319396507712065726965912877889178044489321452540526892581106697213587260581303968314495108439814585421184420014843770161064290389581708297705941888994879327016081279727414348185908077459964865519006267229417152151375452828119103082446114401235115945685219674703882657903762551993641583352385315154281845586882595358954721029880984778088370168635141972524013277223153442722574718130614762581537465586626911838102926072292274274159167780554098619357220471593661193199616071805842054109436528998477753168262245190870602541591290575551503401919575208699092280595
```

Comment: I put the link in the message, also, it's 2 to the power of 82,589,933, i updated that as well in my post

Comment: It's actually 82,589,933, i corrected that as well, it copy pasted odd which led to that, but fixed now

Comment: Ok, now all that's left to do is to do it in Python :-). Easy within seconds with the `decimal` module, btw.

Comment: Not familiar with the how to get the answer with the decimal module, but i did  just now add an answer for an integer based answer.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I guess that works, too, although bit hacky to just hardcode the 24862048. You can do `str(Decimal(2)**82589933 - 1)` after setting `prec` and `Emax` to maximum.